SPSS R^2 for Negative Binomial
I am running a negative binomial regression in SPSS and wondered if there is any way to display R^2 statistics, as would be the case if binary/linear regression was conducted?

It is not at all obvious what $R^2$ should mean in this case.
Is it the squared Pearson correlation between observed and fitted values, $R^2=\left(\text{corr}\left(y, \hat y\right)\right)^2?$
Is it defined by the ratio of the sum of squared residuals to the total sum of squares, $
R^2=1-\left(\dfrac{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\hat y_i
\right)^2
}{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\bar y
\right)^2
}\right)?
$
Is it defined by the ratio of model log-likelihoods that compares the negative binomial log-likelihood of your model to the negative binomial log-likelihood of a null model, $R^2=1-\frac{LL_1}{LL_0}?$
In an ordinary least squares linear model (with an intercept), the first two are equivalent, and an $iid$ Gaussian assumption on the error term leads to the third being equivalent, too.
All of these can be different for a negative binomial regression, and they have different meanings. For that reason, it is not obvious which one should be displayed in a software output. I make a related argument here.

+1 One could argue that for regression the more fundamental formula is $R^2$ = regression SS/Total SS and that the commonly used 1- residual SS/Total SS form is derived from that one (via Regression SS + Residual SS = Total SS in the usual multiple regression model). That form yields still other possibilities when attempting to convert to a negative binomial model. This doesn't alter your basic point of course, but perhaps adds to the plethora of possible (if mainly dubious) attempts to generalize $R^2$ to that case. (It's not like it's all that useful even in the circumstance it came from.)
